# Using youtube-dl in a Windows CMD FOR loop strips non ASCII characters

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, youtube-dl

Running the command with youtube-dl directly in CMD works as expected:

`youtube-dl -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_JXrNAxGzM"`

It correctly gives the title of the Youtube video: **27/12/2016 晚間新聞 楊家駿直播睇手機**

However if I use the same command within a Windows batch file using a FOR loop, the non ASCII characters are removed completely. The batch file code:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('youtube-dl -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_JXrNAxGzM"') DO (
ECHO %%i
)
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Only gives this result: **27/12/2016**

As a test, I tried this:

```
set var=晚間新聞楊家駿直播睇手機

for %%i in (%var%) do (
echo %%i
)
```

Which works fine and [echos the Chinese characters correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nly48.png), this leads me to believe it's not a Unicode problem in CMD, but somehow tied with youtube-dl.

However, I have been assured that it's [not a youtube-dl problem](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/25585#issuecomment-640887361).

Is there something I'm missing and any way to get this working?

Comment: Try using `chcp 65001` before the command. See `chcp /?` also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page

Comment: If you look at the first code block under **Things I've tried**, I have already tested with ```chcp 65001```.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Have you tried any other code pages?

Comment: No I haven't, I was under the impression 65001 was a catch-all approach. However I'm not entirely positive it is a Unicode problem, the non ASCII characters are removed completely from what I can tell, I don't even get question marks or tofu boxes.

Comment: Huh... That is peculiar. When I use Japanese in cmd, it has the question-mark box, but I have never seencharacters just removed and blank.

Comment: My CMD is capable of displaying non ASCII characters, so I don't really understand why using a variable strips them. Comparison between the lines [here](https://i.imgur.com/nJF9S3c.png)

Comment: If you use `set var=あ` or any other non romanized character then `echo %var%` will anything show?

Comment: ```set var=あ``` displays [fine](https://i.imgur.com/zBUGYTv.png).

Comment: you are echoing the character not the variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215541/discussion-between-neko-musume-and-crackerbear).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `--encoding utf-8` switch appears to be working here with `chcp 65001` (disclaimer: only tried under win10 v1909 using the non-legacy console with the NSimSun font, ymmv with other versions or settings).

```
C:\etc>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\etc>for /f "delims=" %i in ('youtube-dl --encoding utf-8 -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_JXrNAxGzM"') do @echo %i
27/12/2016 晚間新聞 楊家駿直播睇手機
```

________

> However, I have been assured that it's not a youtube-dl problem.

The real question to ask the dev is whether `youtube-dl` does any detection of the output stream being sent to the interactive console vs. being piped or redirected, and whether it changes the output encoding based on that detection. I believe the answer to that might be yes, which would explain the difference between direct console output vs. the `for` loop.

Comment: ```--encoding utf-8``` was enough to make it work for me. Thanks a lot, I was baffled by this. Also a thank you to Neko Musume for the help earlier!

Answer (score 2):

As dxiv said `youtube-dl` detects output and input encoding.

Try running with `-v` you'll get in the output line similar to:
`[debug] Encodings: locale cp1255, fs mbcs, out cp1255, pref cp1255`

I noticed on my Hebrew system that I get the line:

```
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1255, fs mbcs, out cp862, pref cp1255
```

for `youtube-dl -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rplmnAxs3aM" -v`

versus

```
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1255, fs mbcs, out cp1255, pref cp1255
```

for `FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('youtube-dl -e "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rplmnAxs3aM" -v') DO ( ECHO %i )`

note that the modern code page for Hebrew is 1255 but the `cmd.exe` on my system defaults to 862 which is the old Hebrew code page.